# Matplotlib TypeError when drawing bar chart from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following code to draw a bar chart from a pandas dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'user':['John Johnson','John Smith','Mary Williams'],
        'attempts':[8955,7881,6723]
})

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
plt.bar(df)
plt.title('Scores by Users')
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

However I get the following error:

> TypeError: bar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'height'

What am I doing wrong? Similar simple chart works well for line charts.

Comment: What you are doing wrong is calling [`plt.bar()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html#matplotlib-pyplot-bar) without the required arguments.

Answer (score 0):

turns out that you can do this by using the following line

```py
plt.bar(df['user'],df['attempts'])
```

instead of

```py
plt.bar(df)
```

it is weird that the line chart worsk so differently from the bar chart

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'user':['John Johnson','John Smith','Mary Williams'],
    'attempts':[8955,7881,6723]})

df.plot(kind='bar')
plt.title('Scores by Users')
```

[image: Graph]

Comment: Could you provide some explanation? _Why_ does this work?

Comment: Please find the documentation for more explanation https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html